# Proving every coset of a kernel is a fiber of a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having trouble with the following problems:

Let $\phi:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism.

a)Prove that ker$\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

b) Prove that every nonempty fiber of $\phi$ is a coset of ker$\phi$, and that every coset of ker$\phi$ is a fiber of $\phi$.

I have managed to prove a), but I am struggling to prove b).

Here is what I have so far:

Suppose we have $\phi (g)=g'$, where $g\in G$ and $g'\in H$. Let $h\in \phi^{-1}(g')$. We know the pre-image is a subset of $G$. So, we know that $\phi(h)=g'=\phi(g)$.

Now, $\phi(h)\phi(g)^{-1}=g'\phi(g)^{-1}=\phi(g)\phi(g)^{-1}$. Therefore, $\phi(g^{-1}h)=e_{H}$. Thus, $g^{-1}h\in$ ker$\phi$. Now, we have that $h=eh=(gg^{-1})h=g(g^{-1}h)\in$ $g$ker$\phi$. Therefore, we know that the pre-image is a subset of a coset of the kernel.

Now, let $x\in$ ker$\phi$. So, $gx\in g$ker$\phi$. Now, $\phi(gx)=\phi(g)\phi(x)=g'$ since $\phi(x)=e$, since it is in the kernel. But this means that $gx\in\phi^{-1}(g')$. So, we know that $g$ker$\phi\subseteq\phi^{-1}(g')$. Due to double containment, we know that every nonempty fiber is a coset of the kernel.

I am having trouble proving the second part of b). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of $b)$.

Let $g\cdot \ker \phi$ be a coset of $\ker \phi$. We denote by $h\in H$ the image of $g$, $h=\varphi(g)$ and claim that $g\cdot \ker \phi = \phi^{-1}(h)$. In other words $g\cdot\ker \phi$ is the fiber corresponding to $h=\varphi(g)$.

Proof: Let $g'\in g\cdot \ker\phi$ then there exists $t\in \ker \phi$ such that $g'=g\cdot t$ we then have $\varphi(g')=\varphi(gt)=\varphi(g)\varphi(t)=h$ hence $g'\in \phi^{-1}(h)$. Thus, $g\cdot \ker \phi \subseteq \phi^{-1}(h)$.

For the other direction, let $g'$ be such that $\varphi(g')=h$ then $\varphi(g^{-1}g')=1$ and so $g^{-1}g'\in\ker\phi$ hence $g'\in g\cdot\ker\phi$ which proves the inclusion in the other direction. We conclude that $g\cdot \ker \phi = \phi^{-1}(h)$ as desired.